# Failed to mount "rpool"

Tags: linux-mint, mount, zfs, automounting, sd-card

I was copying files from a storage drive to the SD card mounted in my Chromebook R11 (Linux Mint) when it locked up. I resorted to turning off and rebooting, my file reader no longer recognizes the SD reader. I show (2) "Failed to mount rpool" "Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0boot0 at /media/joe/rpool: unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member' messages (the other for /dev/mmcblk0boot1)

I'm sure it's a simple zfs fix, but I'm out of my depth here...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like your SD card may have failed.

Comment: Nope It fails to recognize the SD Card Reader